# Javascript onclick and not mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseover, show-hide

```
$(function() {
    $(".popup").hide();
    $(".clickMe").mouseover(function () {       
        $(".popup").show();
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(".popup").hide();//Set this to default hide
    }); 
});

<script type="text/javascript"src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>

<a class="clickMe" href="#"> Click here to see hidden item.</>
<div class="popup"> You've found me! </div>
```

I found this code that i would love to implement but unsure how. Instead of mouseover, how can i set it to onclick call instead? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would do it

```
$(function() { 
  $(".popup").hide();                 //Hide the popup first
  $(".clickMe").click(function () {   //Attach a click event to the .clickMe
        $(".popup").toggle();              //Toggle the visibility of the popup
  });
});
```

So all i've done is change the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events for a single `click` event for the element with a class of `.clickMe`. Then used a jQuery `toggle` effect which will show or display the div depending on whether it is already visible, hence 'toggle' the div. Look [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) for more info

Comment: although your solution is correct, please [make sure the OP showed effort](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/177538).

Comment: @Joseph Was I too eager? :) I'm normally quite hard on people who don't ask suitable questions or dont show code, thought i'd be nice for a change to balance things out.

Comment: No, Mark, you were fine. The OP has is brand new to the site. There's way too many old hands putting the boot in to first-time questioners IMO.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and help, Mark. You've been very helpful. Thanks Nick for your understanding as well. :)

Comment: @Origami Hey, no worries and welcome to stackoverflow. please make sure you read up on some of the rules as you will get more help by following best practices. And take a look here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. At how and why to accept answers (you don't always have to). :)